# 2 Tabs Not Working, Crashes Application

Tags: android

As a beginner, I wanted to learn the tabbed layout of android using tabhost/tabwidget, though I've read some posts that its already deprecated. So... Basically, what I was trying to achieve is to have a layout with two tabs who will both show a webview with different content each. But everytime I try to access that layout, my app crashes.

Here's what it says in my Logcat:

LOGCAT:

```
   04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nicx.amazing/com.nicx.amazing.TabActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachActivity(FragmentManager.java:1844)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:193)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at com.nicx.amazing.TabActivity.onCreate(TabActivity.java:15)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-09 22:30:53.628: E/AndroidRuntime(10406):    ... 11 more
```

Here's what I have in my TabActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        TabHost tHost;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tHost.setup();

            TabHost.TabSpec fb = tHost.newTabSpec("facebook");
            fb.setIndicator("Facebook", null);
            fb.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
            tHost.addTab(fb);

            TabHost.TabSpec tw = tHost.newTabSpec("twitter");
            tw.setIndicator("Twitter", null);
            tw.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
            tHost.addTab(tw);

        }
}
```

NOTE: I still haven't figured out how to place a webview in my tabs, I just want to start first in seeing the layout of my tabs.

I also have this in my activity_tab.xml:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I used http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/ as a guide. I just didn't follow its fragments since I am not using it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Why is `android:layout_weight="0"` in <TabWidget>?

Comment: Also remove super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); since you call it twice

Comment: @TimCastelijns I just followed what the link says, and also because everytime I try to change it, the tab moves vertically and not on top only.

Comment: @MarcinS. Already removed that but still gets the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, dear, there must also be two activities stands for Facebook and Twitter, do you leave them behind?

You have to create those activity to complete your app.

And I find that your TabActivity extends from FrameActivity, which doesn't seem right.
Your MainActivity should extend TabActivity.

And here is an examle of mine

```
package com.izzyleung.mixedbartest;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
    imageIntent.setClass(this, ImageActivity.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec imageSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Image");
    imageSpec.setIndicator("Image");
    imageSpec.setContent(imageIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(imageSpec);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    notificationIntent.setClass(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec notificationSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Notification");
    notificationSpec.setIndicator("Notification");
    notificationSpec.setContent(notificationIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(notificationSpec);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent();
        settingsIntent.setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   }
}
```

And my XML file goes like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5sp" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5sp" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're awesome! I finally got it. I really am confused about those specs and intents. Thank you so much! Now I can try working on the webview. Can I ask a question again? The class that is shown in the intent portion [imageIntent.setClass(this, ImageActivity.class);], is that the way to show the content of the tab?

Comment: Yep, that's the way to show the tab content. :) I met the same problem as you met when dealing with TabActivity, and I found my way to solve it on the Internet. Google now recommend us to do so by Fragment, however, I'm still trying to figure out how to use Fragment.